SEVERE: Allocate exception for servlet
I was previously using NetBeans IDE in Windows 10. I got a new PC with Windows 11. Both NetBeans IDE and Eclipse IDE are installed. In NetBeans IDE, while trying to configure the tomcat server, I got the following error:enter image description here. I shifted to Eclipse IDE and configured the tomcat server (version 9.0). I migrated the project from NetBeans IDE to Eclipse IDE. While trying to run the project in eclipse, I received the following error
Oct 10, 2024 7:43:44 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Marking servlet [liveData] as unavailable
Oct 10, 2024 7:43:44 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Allocate exception for servlet [liveData]
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.bhel.servlets.LiveData
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1365)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1188)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:539)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:520)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1042)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:761)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:135)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:690)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:373)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1590)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)


My web.xml file is as below:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
    <!--servlet description-->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>liveData</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.bhel.servlets.LiveData</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>MonData</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.bhel.servlets.MonData</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>hConData</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.bhel.servlets.hConData</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>liveData</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/ld</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>conData</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.bhel.servlets.conData</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>AllConData</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.bhel.servlets.AllConData</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>AllConData</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/allcd</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>ProductWise</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.bhel.servlets.ProductWiseData</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>ProductWise</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/pro_grp</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>conData</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/cd</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>MonData</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/md</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>hConData</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/hcd</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
</web-app>


Can some one please point me out where am I going wrong. Here is my deployment description window:enter image description here
I am receiving the above exception for whatever I tried. Please help me in fixing this. Thank you.
